# Desktop not loading after unsuccessfull password change

Tags: 11.04, nautilus

First of all - yes, i acted like a fool. I decided to change password in 11.04, and process took so long, so i hit cancel and then even turned laptop off, because everything was dead. After that i turned it back on and got all those errors about .ICEAuthority update, and Nautilus not able to create Desktop and .nautilus folders. I changed my password back using passwd in console, even re-installed nautilus package(fortunately, unity was gone), but still desktop is not loading, same error messages. Sometimes i get pieces of desktop, like background image or top bar with menus, but it happens very seldom and they never come together. I also created new user and tried to log in using this new account, but received same error messages, but for this user.

Is there a way to recover my desktop? Of course i already got used to lynx, mplayer and fbi, but desktop would be a really nice thing to have :)

I also can't perform fresh install because despite the fact that i got ubuntu distro on my hard drive i cant burn it to a usb stick, because, well, i don't know how.

Comment: This is usually a permissions issue. Check the permissions and ownership on your home folder.

Comment: This question appears to be abandoned, if you are experiencing a similar issue please [ask a new question](http://askubuntu.com/questions/ask) with details pertaining to your problem. If you feel this question is *not* abandoned, please flag the question explaining that. I am flagging this for closure. Regards,